# Exclude certain values being displayed from a csv file

Tags: javascript, php, css, csv

This question has been revised as on reflection I was approaching this
wrong.

What I need to do is ONLY display the highlighted values, so if
LLOBLEVEL is less than ILEVEL it highlights the value on screen.
Therefore excluding outputs that dont equal less than ILEVEL<.

Any help will be much appriciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(it) {
  if ((it.style.backgroundColor == "none") || (it.style.backgroundColor == ""))
    {it.style.backgroundColor = "#CCC";}
  else
    {it.style.backgroundColor = "";}
}
</script>
<?php include 'levels.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$total = count($lloblevel_val);
for ($i=0; $i< $total; $i++) {
$name = '';
$level = '';
$lob = '';
if ($iname_val[$i]) {
  $name = '<span id="title">' . $iname_val[$i] . '</span><br/>';
}

if ($ilevel_val[$i] < $lloblevel_val[$i]) {
  $level = '<span class="highlight">' . $ilevel_val[$i] . '</span><br/>';
}

 if ($lloblevel_val[$i] > $ilevel_val[$i]) {
{
  $lob = '<span class="highlight">' . $lloblevel_val[$i] . '</span><br/>';
}

?>
<table id="highlighted">
<tr onClick="toggle(this)">
  <td class="tdl"><?php print $name; ?></td>
  <td class="tdr"><?php print $lob; ?></td>
  <td class="tdr"><?php print $level; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

levels.php

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,",");

if(!$next_line) {
    $iname_val[] = $line_of_text[1];
    $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[5];
    $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[3];
}

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search in the `$line_of_text` array the word that you don't want.

```
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,",");
$words_to_discard=array("DESKTOP PC","another word","0337");  //here, you put all the wors to discard

foreach ($words_to_discard as $word){
    if(stristr($line_of_text[1],$word) !== FALSE) 
    $next_line=1;
}

if(!$next_line) {
    $iname_val[] = $line_of_text[1];
    $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[5];
    $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[3];
        echo  $line_of_text[1]."-". $line_of_text[5]."-". $line_of_text[3]."<br>";
}

}
```

EDIT

Using this code, with this csv file (your csv file):

```
ItemNumber,ItemTitle,Level,MinimumLevel,InOrderBook,Level_LessOrderBook
"VBI4-0332","DES2OP PC--- VBI4-0332","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0333","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0333","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0334","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0334","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0335","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0335","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0336","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0336","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0337","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0337","20","0","0","20"
```

will output:

```
ItemTitle-Level_LessOrderBook-MinimumLevel
DES2OP PC--- VBI4-0332-20-0
```

Comment: This is what I need but it displays 1 - 5 -3 on one row. The word would be in the line of text 1. How can I stop it displaying all 3 line of text using this method? Also the current method gives this error Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /homepages/9/d422628380/htdocs/stock/levels.php on line 10

Comment: check if in your csv file are a blank space at the end, remove it.
also, can you give an example of your csv file? you could use false data.

Comment: That got rid of the error but now it just displays an empty table. 3 Columns and several rows. Any ideas?

Comment: that is because, in my csv file, i use ";" as delimiter, put your delimiter in fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,";");

Comment: <?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("stockexport.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024,",");

    $word_to_discard='DEKSTOP PC';
    if (!in_array($word_to_discard, $line_of_text)) {
          $iname_val[] = $line_of_text[1];
          $ilevel_val[] = $line_of_text[5];
          $lloblevel_val[] = $line_of_text[3];

    }

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>

I have used the delimiter that is in my csv file. it now shows me the information but dosent get rid of any rows with desktop pc in them. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please, post an example of your csv file.. your word to discar is "DEKSTOP PC" or "desktop pc"?

Comment: ItemNumber,ItemTitle,Level,MinimumLevel,InOrderBook,Level_LessOrderBook
"VBI4-0332","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0332","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0333","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0333","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0334","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0334","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0335","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0335","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0336","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0336","20","0","0","20"
"VBI4-0337","DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-0337","20","0","0","20"

Comment: ahhh, is nos only DESKTOP PC, it have more letters, like DESKTOP PC--- VBI4-033x.

Comment: I have lots of different variations is there a way of it finding a part of the words? So I don't have to type them in manually?

Comment: It does work but its getting rid of alot of other stuff I dont want it too... :/ abit lost why it has got rid of all entry's that begin with a  letters?

Comment: what other words do you want to discards?

Comment: It discards more than DESKTOP PC... it gets rid of most of the csv for some reason?

Comment: can you send me your csv file? kraysak gmail,com, 
or, maybe that word is in all the file..

Comment: I think im approching this totally wrong, on realisation I should have asked to ONLY display what the highlighted rows are.... then this would mean I dont have to enter specific words. So if the LLOBLEVEL < than the iLEVEL it will highlight and exclude any values that dont need attention to them. Sorry but It does make more sense and maybe its easier? what do you think?

Comment: LLOBLEVEL and iLEVEL are columns in the csv file?,i don't understand what you want now

Comment: I have revised the whole question above for space. please see kraysak :)

Comment: please, can you give an example of what do you want to get... i really don't understand you

Comment: Initially i wanted to exclude certain words but on reflection In the future I will have to keep adding words which I do not want to do. I now want to display the information which highlights its self if the stock level (lloblevel) is less  than the minimum level (ilevel) ** lloblevel < ilevel = hightlight ** i only want this information displaying in the table.

Comment: Do you get what I mean kraysak?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help

`if (preg_match("DESKTOP PC", $array)) { Do something }`

Also here's a link explaining it https://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: That is an example for a case where you should _not_ use regular expressions. You are searching for a _static_ value here, so a simple string function like `strpos` will do fine.